# Send bulk emails without timeout

Tags: email, wp-mail

I am developing a plugin that sends emails out to users. I am having difficulty in finding the most performance enhanced way to send these emails out and prevent a server timeout. In other words, I would like my plugin to scale, so if someone that uses it on a site with a hundred thousand users, my plugin will still work. Perhaps there is a way to execute each email or two as a separate script that gets executed one after another? Some help/insight on this would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Had you researched what exactly is becoming your bottleneck? This might be more of a server software question.

Answer (score -2):

The [MailPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mailpress/) does a good job of sending 1000's of emails so it might be worth examining the source code to see how it works.